# Laravel eloquent with archive table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables with same schema.

```
TABLE: items, items_archive

+-------------+-------------------
| partno |qty | brand|| category |
+--------------------------------+
|        |    |      |           |
|        |    |      |           |
|        |    |      |           |
+--------+----+------+-----------+
```

Is there any way to  create a eloquent model which i can use to query from both at same time?

Item::where('brand', 'acer') => which will query will do something like union.

Comment: Why do your 2 tables have the same schema? Wouldn't it make more sense to use 1 table and differentiate between the data with a `type` column?

Comment: Apparently the tables belong to another software (accounting), that software archives the data and moves to archive table periodically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to take an approach like this:

```
$a = Item::where('brand', 'acer');
$b = ItemArchive::where('brand', 'acer');
$results = $a->union($b)->get();`
```

In this, we are creating 2 models with search queries, but not executing them. Finally, we `union` them together and the `get()` the results. You can then loop through the `$results` array for all the data.

Alternatively, you could hide all this logic inside your `Item` model:

```
public function retrieveAllWithArchive($brand) 
{
   return $this->where('brand', $brand)->union((new ItemArchive)->where('brand', $brand))->get();
}
```

Then, call it from anywhere with:

```
$results = (new Item)->retrieveAllWithArchive($brand);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
Do you think there is any solution which combines and do the union?

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help